# Sort table entries then divide into groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I would like to sort through a table (Lessons) and group them by Subject(A field in the Lesson's table).  Then display them by subject.

So I would have a header: Subject

Then it would display the image, title and description for each item in that subject.
Then it would move onto the next Subject and so on up to 5 items

For example:

```
Math
[img]   [img]   [img]  ...
title   title   title  ...
desc    desc    desc   ...

Science
[img]   [img]   [img]  ...
title   title   title  ...
desc    desc    desc   ...

etc.....
```

In the controller how would you go about sorting and then dividing up?

How do you display this in the view if you have a dynamic amount of subjects?

Comment: How is the subject stored? Is it its own model that `has_many` Lessons?

Comment: Sorry...I should have wrote it out better.  Subject is a column in the lesson's table

Comment: It should probably be a different table with a has_many lessons. The way you have it is denormalized, and in general [normalized data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meat of your needs are met by [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html):

```
my_lessons.sort_by{ |lesson|
  # Or use ActiveRecord to sort your data
  lesson.title
}.group_by{ |lesson|
  lesson.subject
}.each do |subject,subj_lessons|
  puts "subject: #{subject}"
  subj_lessons.each do |lesson|
    puts lesson.title
  end
end
```

Whatever you return from group_by will be the key for your hash, while the value (`subj_lessons`) is an array of all the items that matched that grouping.

Modify this to fit your actual data and your output needs.